# GNOME - change dash icon size

Tags: gnome-shell

How can I make the icon size in the side dash bigger?

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with vanilla GNOME.

Comment: Vanilla GNOME session without dock

Comment: Sorry, @karel, your edit clearly conflicts with OP's intent (see the comment above).

Comment: Maybe you could install dash to dock and configure it to behave as the regular gnome dash while also increasing it's size.